# Imagemagick GraphicsMagick image mean command

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick, imagemagick-identify

I use the following command that works in imagemagick to get the mean of a picture

```
identify -format "%[mean]" photo.jpg
```

the same command does not work under graphicsmagick. Is there an equivalent I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, for example:

```
gm identify -verbose photo.jpg | grep -E "Mean|Red|Green|Blue"
```

Or, if you want Red, Green and Blue as 3 separate integers

```
gm identify -verbose photo.jpg | awk '/Mean:/{s=s int($2) " "} END{print s}'
0 29 225
```

Or, if you want the average of all channels, like this:

```
gm identify -verbose photo.jpg | awk '/Mean:/{n++;t+=$2} END{print int(t/n)}'
85
```

Comment: I am using im4java to interact with graphicsmagick so the mix of the gm command and grep or awk is a bit complicated for me but I will try it with Java's Processbuilder. Thank you very much for taking the time to reply